# apache server's configuration

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have a apache server and my index html files looks like 
index-en.html, index-fr.html

Here is a configuration

```
#
# Configure the DocumentRoot
#
DocumentRoot "/usr/lib/suite/utilities/proxy/web"

AddLanguage en .en
AddLanguage zh-CN .zh-CN
AddLanguage ja .ja
AddLanguage de .de
LanguagePriority en

<Directory "/usr/lib/suite/utilities/proxy/web">
        Options +MultiViews
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
#
# Force clients to reload index file - no caching
#
  <Files "index*.html">
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
      Header unset ETag
      Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
      Header set Pragma "no-cache"
      Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    </ifModule>
  </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /ui "/usr/lib/tomcat-web-app/webapps/ui"
<Directory "/usr/lib/tomcat-web-app/webapps/ui">
        Options None
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        ExpiresDefault "access plus
```

The locate to localhost/ui i get this error:

```
  Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.
```

How can I correct configure my apache config. Thanks

Comment: `ls -ld /usr/lib/tomcat-web-app/webapps/ui` to see the permissions, then check each directory up from there to make sure that your `www` (or whatever) user has `read` and `execute` privileges (technically, you only need exec). Do you have an `index.html` file in that directory?

Comment: No, I change my index.html file to this format index-{locale}.html. I would like to understand is it require to use index.html.{locale} file, or I can use another format

Comment: If you request `.../index-en.html` (for example), does that work? If so, httpd is configured (in general) correctly. You need to read the [httpd documentation on content-negotiation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) and adjust your configuration accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, when I request  .../index-en.html it works